# Return whether a Node has a certain relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spatial

I have this query:

```
START store=node:LocationIndex('withinDistance:[40.0,20.30,11.0]'), u=node(111) 
MATCH store-[:rents]->(m:Movie)
OPTIONAL MATCH u-[r:isFav]-m
RETURN DISTINCT store, m
```

and I'm trying to return true in case the node `m` is related with `u` via `:isFav` relationship.
My first approach was using OPTIONAL MATCH but it is similar to an OUTER JOIN, returning all the movies in the database, even if they're not in the stores.

I know in Neo4j 2.1.5 there's an EXIST function that fits perfectly with this but I'm using 2.1.2 because otherwise Spatial doesn't work.

Could you please help me with the best way of returning this boolean?

Comment: I'd probably turn it around, to go first to the user's favorites and then add the optional match between the movie and the store.

Comment: I think I did It using "START MATCH stores WITH stores"; and then "MATCH faves and RETURN" in the same query. I dunno why in this case it doesn't act like an OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 0):

This query will return an `isStoreNearby` boolean. For efficiency, it stops the query as soon as a single nearby store is found that rents a favorite movie of the user.

```
START store=node:LocationIndex('withinDistance:[40.0,20.30,11.0]'), u=node(111) 
MATCH store-[:rents]->(m:Movie)-[r:isFav]-u
RETURN COUNT(m) > 0 AS isStoreNearby
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks but, actually, what I want is a list of movies in nearby stores and a boolean for each one of them saying whether is fav or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine to achieve what your comment on Cybersam's answer says. All you need to add is the boolean field:

```
START store=node:LocationIndex('withinDistance:[40.0,20.30,11.0]'), u=node(111) 
MATCH store-[:rents]->(m:Movie)
OPTIONAL MATCH u-[r:isFav]-m
RETURN store, m, COUNT(r) > 0 AS fav
```

If you are seeing results that you do not expect, can you confirm how the query behaves without the optional match component, maybe your location search is returning more than you expect?